# How can I use a changing variable in two files

Tags: php, global-variables

So I have a variable like `$mapname = date('YmdHis');`, this variable changes every second.. I want to use it accross files but the problem is that the date changes every second and that the two different files execute their script not on the same time..

So when I submit my form I get two folders for instance called: 20150113132538 and 20150113132547. The script checks if there exists a folder based on $mapname. but because one script is slower then the other (depending on your upload speed because it uploads files) it creates a new folder because the folder doesn't exist.

Anyone has a solution for this?

---

Here is the code from the two scripts, require date.php is basically putting this `$mapname = date('YmdHis');` in the file

The script down here is called by this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function SaveIt() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var myDrawing = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
        var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("image/png");
        var postData = "canvasData="+drawingString;
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST",'saveimage.php',true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4)
                {alert("image saved");}
            }
            ajax.send(postData);
    }
    </script>
```

This code opens the saveimage.php down here

```
<?php
$upload_dir = "uploads/";

require_once "date.php";

if (!file_exists($upload_dir.$mapname)) {
    mkdir("uploads/".$mapname, 0777, true);
    }

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $rawImage=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $removeHeaders=substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
    $decode=base64_decode($removeHeaders);
    $fopen = fopen( 'uploads/'.$mapname.'/test.jpg', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fopen, $decode);
    fclose( $fopen );
}
?>
```

^ This is the script to upload my (sketch) canvas.

```
require_once "date.php";

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $path = "" . $upload_dir . "/" . $mapname . "/"; // Upload directory

    // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }

        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            elseif(!$_POST["fancier"]){
                $message[] = "Please fill in your name.";
                continue;
            }           
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
                if (!file_exists($path)) {
                    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                }
                if (file_exists($path.$name)) {
                    $path_parts = pathinfo($name);
                    $name = $path_parts['filename'] . "_" . date('ynjGis') . "." . $path_parts['extension'];
                }
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {
                    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

^ And this uploads multiple images.

The image(s) size(s) are bigger then the canvas, so the canvas script is loaded in 1/2 seconds, whilst the uploading takes about 9/10 seconds.. thuss creating two different folders based on the current date.

Comment: any code which will help us? aka an example

Comment: I'll post it in a sec

Comment: 2 scripts executing implies 2 requests. In a stateless environment (such as PHP), no variable, global or otherwise, will retain its value. Maybe a session could help

Comment: That or put the mapname into a hidden variable as the time when the page is rendered vs when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Jonnycake: disk I/O is still a major bottleneck... use a session, not a temp file, honestly. Besides: how are you going to distinguish what user is uploading what file? create a tempfile per user? That would be terrible

Comment: Sessions won't work for me since I'm working with two PHP files

Comment: `Sessions won't work for me since I'm working with two PHP files` WAT? That's exactly why only sessions will work for you! -_-

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a PHP noob, I tried using Sessions but it still made two different folders for me based on the time. All I need is basically a way to lock the time variable untill after the form is submitted :s

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm not saying a temp file, I'm saying a hidden form field that gets submitted when the form is.  So when he outputs the form, do echo "<input type='hidden' name='outputtime' value='".time()."'/>"...then when it's submitted you can take $_REQUEST['outputtime'] and create the folder.



Branco: Could it be possible that you forgot session_start() at the top of the script?  I haven't really looked at your code to see what you're trying to accomplish, but that's the only reason I can think for sessions not to work

Answer (score 1):

Set `$GLOBALS['mapname']` in the script you're accessing in your browser and use it from the other scripts, which I assume you `require` or `include` in that first script.

The variable will keep its content throughout the whole request. You might even use a constant to prevent overwriting it like so:

```
if(!defined('MAPNAME')) {
    define('MAPNAME', date('YmdHis'));
}
```

Comment: I know, but I don't think thats the case here, he's just being unclear. Keep in mind he's talking about a single form submission.